# Does Android have a 2.1GB file size limit?

Tags: file-system

I have tried many voice recording type applications and the best I have found only allows me to do a recording upto a maximum file size of 2.1GB.  I can do many of these 2.1GB recordings as I have a fairly large SD card.

On one of the applications I have tried, the developer has specifically said that his/her app has no recording length limit

So my question, does Android have a built in 2.1GB limit per file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes

More Detailed Answer:

The file size limit is not something specific to Android, it is a limit of the File System.

It may "technically" be a bug in Android though, as FAT32, which is what the file system is for the sdcard, should have a file size limit of 4GB ((2^32)-1 = 4,294,967,295B) but it looks like the filesystem on Android is android is actually using a limit of ((2^31) - 1 = 2,147,483,647B). Which means they could be using signed integers, instead of unsigned integers for the addressing on the filesystem.

Comment: The **yes** only qualifies for devices with integrated SD cards, aka **not** Google's Nexus line (Nexus S, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 7) amongst others. And most probably not for most Jelly Bean devices (/mnt/sdcard  is a symlink to /data/media which is *not* FAT)

Comment: Do you have some document or evidence about this limitation?