# Transfer a large file from PC to smartphone

Tags: usb, file-transfer, file-system

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2, and a PC with Windows XP (I do not have WiFi). I want to transfer a 2.1 GB file from the computer to the phone. If I transfer the file as usual, I have the following error:

> Failed to copy the selected files. Not enough free space on the
>   device.

I think my problem is related to the type of the file system. What is the solution of my problem is there?

Comment: Are you copying it to the internal memory? Or the external SD card? Have you also check how much memory you have free?

Comment: I don't think your problem is related to the type of file system, because even FAT32 supports files as large as 4GB. Are you sure there is at least 2.1 GB free space available on your phone/SDcard?

Comment: @geff_chang, I am copying it to the internal memory. I have approximately 8GB of free memory.

Comment: @yrajabi, yes, I'm sure, because this phone is new, and the computer shows that the phone has about 8GB of free memory.

Comment: Be aware that though not a limiot of the file system (according to specs), many Android devices have a file size limit of ~2G (see: [Does Android have a 2.1GB file size limit?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27471/16575)).

Comment: @Izzy, I downloaded maps of my city on my local torrent. They weigh approximately 2.1 GB. The installation instructions say that I need to move the cards on the phone. How to do it?

Comment: Ask the dev, I cannot tell. If it's not supported on your phone, either the dev makes a "smaller version", or no-go I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

first and foremost you should have your memory more than 2.1GB.
secondly,check the file type i.e FAT32 or not.please check the specs of your mobile.you generally get this message when you transfer a file onto a oc.[please go through the link specified](http://www.cknow.com/cms/articles/why-cant-i-copy-a-large-file-despite-having-larger-free-space.html)